# loading static google map

Tags: java, swing, google-maps

I have tried to load a static google map in the following lines of code.

```
The request to connect to the specified URL has failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at StaticGoogleMap.init(StaticGoogleMap.java:36)
at StaticGoogleMap.main(StaticGoogleMap.java:66)
```

Code:

```
  public class StaticGoogleMap extends JPanel
    {
        private JLabel label;
        private JFrame frame;
        private ImageIcon icon;
        private URLConnection con;
        private URL url;




        public void init()
        {
            try 
            {
            url=new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false");
            con = url.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(is);
            icon=new ImageIcon(img);
            label=new JLabel(icon);
            add(label);
            frame=new JFrame("Google Map");
            frame.add(this,java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setSize(500,500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            is.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new StaticGoogleMap().init();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete exception message?

Comment: I have had a lot of connections delays with Google this evening as well.  Seems to be better now.  Might want to catch that exception, though.